# Is it possible to select dynamically a field to use in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have something like this : 
class A :

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class A {
   @Fields({
      @Field(name="a"....)
      @Field(name="b"....)
   )}
   private String someField;
      ....
   }
}
```

And class B:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class B {
   @IndexedEmbedded
   @ManyToOne
   private A a;
   ......
}
```

I would like to use @Field 'a' when indexing etity 'A' and @Field 'b' when indexing entity 'b' ! Is it possible to do that ? 
Because lucene index for the class 'B' contains the same field twice (a.someString) but I don't need that, I need just one field for this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible by just using annotations. One solution would be to write a custom field bridge for the many-to-one association `a` in class `B`. By writing a custom field bridge you can control yourself which fields you want to index for an instance of type `A`. The disadvantage of course is that you have to manage the indexing of all properties yourself.

The more important question imo is, why you want this conditional indexing? Do you have a specific problem? I don't think that adding both fields in both cases will affect your search performance. At most your index gets a bit bigger, but unless you are hitting some actual problem/barrier I would not be concerned about this.

**UPDATE:**

Actually, there is a feature you could use to control this. You can use the `includePaths` property of `@IndexedEmbedded` allowing you to explicitly control which fields get added to the index. So in your case:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class B {
   @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths="a.b")
   @ManyToOne
   private A a;
   ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hardy, it is not a matter of performance, I just don't want a bigger index which I don't fully use.

Comment: Have you compared the sizes to see how much the index size differs in both cases?

Comment: Yes it's possible, use '@IndexedEmbedded(includePaths= ' to specify which field names it should include. When you use this feature, all other fields will be excluded. @Hardy could you amend your answer please?

Comment: Tanks Sanne, I've just seen that in the book hibernate search by example